# "where" condition not working correctly in join query in JPA (native query)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot Starter Web with MYSQL and JPA. I have created Entities as:

**parent:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Parent{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "control_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private List<Child> childList;

}
```

**Child:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   private Long control_id;
   private Boolean is_active;

}
```

I have 2 DAOs for both of them as

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface ParentDao extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM parent as p inner join child as c on p.id = c.control_id WHERE (c.is_active = 1 and p.id = :entry_id)", nativeQuery = true)
    Parent findActiveById(@Param("entry_id") Long aLong);
}

@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface ChildDao extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {
      
}
```

Here what I am trying to achieve is, I want to fetch an Object of Parent with all the Child which are active. but this returns everything, is_active = 1 as well as 0.

Comment: You cannot do this, if you need only active children, fetch separately using `ChildDao` using `control_id` and `is_active` and then fetch parent separately and write your logic.

Comment: can you suggest the approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have child repository which you can use to fetch children

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface ChildDao extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {
      // Method in this manner will be automatically converted into a query
      List<Child> findByControl_idAndIs_active(Long control_id, Boolean is_active);
}

// Use it like this
List<Child> children = childDao.findByControl_idAndIs_active(control_id, true); 

// Then fetch the Parent separately or can fetch before also
Optional<Parent> parent = parentDao.findById(parent_id);
```

If you are wondering from where these methods came then please [See This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

But if you want to fetch parent and child both in one query as a same structure then it wouldn't be possible, one thing you can do is fetch using custom query into a List of Dto with required fields and then create parent-child like structure in your code.

One suggestion, you should name variable in camel case in java i.e controlId instead of control_id and use `@column(name='control_id')` but its your choice :)

Comment: So what you are saying is I should fetch child list first and then set that into parent object? if that is the case then, when we call parentDao.findById(id); it fetches all the data which makes api really slow, because there will be more than 1000 inactive childs. how do I stop this, so that it will only fetch parent Object without child list??

Comment: In my answer, I have suggested to fetch `children` in separate call, not using `parent`, I have included parent thinking that you might need some information from parent object to include in you logic. You have not given the whole use case what you want to do, if only the active children you want to fetch then fetch them using you condition using `ChildDao` if you want in both parent and child in one query, you need custom query, it cannot be done the way you are thinking, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `join fetch child` instead of `join child` in order that JPA uses only one SQL Query and returns the parent items having the good child

Answer (score 0):

You need to return only the parent, not the whole join. As it is, your query returns a collection of parent and child joined together.

```
SELECT p FROM parent p inner join child c on p.id = c.control_id WHERE (c.is_active = 1 and p.id = :entry_id)
```

Comment: it returns with 2020-09-11 19:52:49.851 ERROR 12876 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'p' in 'field list'

Comment: Since it's a native query you'd want `SELECT p.* FROM ...`